# Stylus, right order of subdirectory import

Tags: css, import, subdirectory, stylus

everybody.
I have a problem with stylus import.
In my project I'am using such methode of import:
`@import "project/**/*.styl"`

And also i have this bem folder structure:

`Project/
 |- Project.styl
 |- Block1/
 | |- Block1.styl
 | |- _Element1/
 | | |- _Element1.styl
 | | |- __Modificator1/
 | | | |- __Modificator1.styl
 |- Block2/
 |- Block3/`

In general, the problem is that when bundle.css is ready, styles in it goes in wrong way. First in it goes modificators, then elements and only then blocks, so modificator always overwrites by elements, and finnaly they don't work ... that how looks my code:

HTML:

`<div class="block1_element1 block1_element1__modificator1"></div>`

CSS:

`.block1_element1__modificator1{font-size: 14px}
.block1_element1{font-size: 16px}`

In result will be 16px font size ...

If someone know how to change order from end of branch to the start, please give me advice how to make it.s

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**
Wrong order of Stylus imported files.

**The Reason**
When using *File Globing* in Stylus i.e. `**/*` Stylus engine orders files by **names** so the order of imported files becomes `__Modificator(n).styl` then `_Element(n).styl` then `Block(n).styl` and that of course what is causing wrong CSS styles.

**Possible Solution**
Use `index.styl` file in each directory/subdirectory, inside each `index.styl` file import all the files in the current directory then all `index.styl` files of all subdirectories.

**Example**
The project structure should be like below:

```
Project/
 |- Project.styl
 |- Block1/
 | |- index.styl
 | |- Block1.styl
 | |- _Element1/
 | | |- index.styl
 | | |- _Element1.styl
 | | |- __Modificator1/
 | | | |- index.styl
 | | | |- __Modificator1.styl
 |- Block2/
 |- Block3/
```

And here what should be inside the `index.styl` files

```
inside Project.styl
@import "Block1"
@import "Block2"
...

inside any Block directory index.styl file
@import "_Element1"
@import "_Element2"
@import "Block1.styl" // current parent block
...

inside any Element directory index.styl file
@import "__Modificator1"
@import "__Modificator2"
@import "_Element1.styl" // current parent Element
...
```

Comment: It`s funny, but when I was working with SASS, I was using exact same method for import files, but instead of **index**, was **install** files. And for that reason i decide to replace SASS by Stylus. So it realy sad if it have such cool feature, but it totaly uncofigurable ...

Comment: AFAIK Sass also imports files in alphabetic order.

Comment: hmm... When i was trying same import combination, it was not work for me on SASS... Strange...